# How to use nested inline asp.net tags?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to display a link with Html.ActionLink.

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("HOME", "Index") %>
```

Instead of using the word "HOME", I would like to use string from resource file because I need multiple languages.

```
<%$ Resources:Site, MenuHome %>
```

In this case, how to nested these tags?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(Resources.Site, "Index") %>
```

which assumes that you have a `Resources.resx` file in the `App_GlobalResources` special folder and a `Site` key inside it.